# PHP "Loaded Configuration File" where is it set?

Tags: php, apache

As I understand the default location for php.ini file is /etc/php.ini.  However, on my server php.ini location is set to load from a different directory. Where do I set where php.ini should be loaded from?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 0):

> PHP_INI_SYSTEM can be configured per-directory by placing it inside a
>   per-directory block in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code below in a script (blank test php file if possible):

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Load this script in your browser and then search for "Loaded Configuration File" which will contain the exact location of the php.ini file.

Comment: I think the question was not finding out which ini is being used, but how it was set that way in the first place.